# How to Record the steps user performs in an app in text format?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, user-interface

I need to record the steps a user performs while he is using an application of which I do not have the source code.

Which is the best way to do such a thing? Where should I start?

For Example: Say my application is notepad, the log might look like this:

```
1. Click on File Menu
2. Click on New...
3. Type "How are you?"
4. Click on Edit Menu
5. Click on Select All
```

etc.

Comment: Basically I have to create a Tutorial/manual for that application, so i cant modify the code, i just have the exe, and the manual need not have any images, text based is what im looking for..

Comment: How big is your app. It sounds like it would take longer to write the tool to record the steps than it would take to write the tutorial.

Comment: I don't think this question "is not a real question", even though the quality was rather low.

Comment: i need to do this frequently, and its a pretty large application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are really looking for is a "Test Suite", or a key logger. For control names you can use application like Spy++ or, better yet, if its WPF/Window Forms use Snoop.

Answer (score 0):

For every action the user makes, you should implement a callback (eventhandler, depending on which language you use) method. This method then writes a line to a file. That line describes what the function does.

It's eventsbased programming like in C# ;)

Comment: The application (in the given example notepad) is not mine, i cant do any changes to that..